# How can I select the apps to sync when auto-sync is turned on?

Tags: sync, google-account

When I turn on auto sync it sync all my accounts like Google, Twitter, Facebook, BBM etc.

How can I set auto sync to sync only selected accounts so that only my Google or Twitter account will be sync?

Comment: Gee, Bill. I'm surprised you're not using a Windows phone.

Comment: @AlE Even Bill knows that Android is better.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at *Settings → Accounts & Sync?* (I'm not sure about Android 4.1+, but at least on my *LG Optimus 4X* this setting is there)

[image: Accounts & Sync]
<sup>*Accounts & Sync* (click image for larger variant)</sup>

As the screenshot shows, here you can define what to sync. Green arrows to the right show what's to be sync'd, gray ones what not. For some apps, you even can tap the app to specify it more detailed.

Comment: What version of Android/manufacturer-added skin is that in your screen shot? It doesn't match up with my vanilla Android 4.2. (In fact, there isn't an "Accounts & Sync" option in settings.)

Comment: I cannot check with 4.2, as my LG O4X still runs 4.0, and it has "Accounts & Sync" in settings. OP didn't state which Android version he refers to – but you're right, I should state mine with the answer *(updating...)*

Comment: @AlEverett vanilla Android 4.2 & 4.3 have an "Accounts" heading in Settings and just list all your sync accounts under that heading in the main settings screen. You can tap to open those accounts and most of them should have sync options that you can un-tick.

Comment: And it's still there with Android 4.4, by the way. Most likely also with later versions.

Answer (score -2):

For Android 4.2+:

- Accounts -> Select account -> More (at the top right) -> Sync.